# How to add motion blur to the moving object

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

I am using translate property to make a custom mouse move  on the document based on the x and y coordinates of the mouse. Now I want to add a little motion blur effect to the custom moving object in order to make

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  document.querySelector('.mover').style.transform = `translate(${event.pageX}px, ${event.pageY}px)`
  
});
```

```css
.mover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -8px;
  top: -6px;
  transition-duration: .15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

html {
  cursor: none;
}

body {
  background: #F5F9FF;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mover">
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M12,11.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 9.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,6.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 14.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,11.5M12,2A7,7 0 0,0 5,9C5,14.25 12,22 12,22C12,22 19,14.25 19,9A7,7 0 0,0 12 ,2Z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

it look smooth and good.

Comment: Could you please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question? Especially the Javascript is useless, it might not even be Javascript? As you can see in [this CopePen](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/OJajdVz) your code doesn't work.

Comment: When I test your code the cursor moves _very smoothly_, it even feels sluggish. The latter is clearly due to the `transition-duration: .15s;`. I'm not quite sure what other effect you want to achieve? On what device are you testing this? I'm using a Windows desktop and tested various browsers.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, The effect I want  is a little motion blur, .i.e, a little blur when its moving,

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, The custom cursor is moving smoothly, but its static image the whole time, I want a little blur effect on the object when moving

Comment: Yes, I understand it. This is not so easy. It might require an animation instead of a transition. I'll leave this for others to answer. 

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, Its okay, Thank you for trying, would you please mind upvoting so it can get some more attention :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try with:

filter: blur(3px) opacity(.8);

and adjust a little bit the parameters

Comment: that is not motion blur. that is just blur.